# Exclude phrase from search in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I'm using ElasticSearch (elasticsearch-dsl) and searching for keywords, but would like to ignore some phrases from search. E.g. searching for `"best"` and ignore phrase `"best regards"`:
it should find document "The `Best` Car bla-bla-bla Best Regards" (first match is correct, second one ignored), but shouldn't match "Bla-bla-bla Best Regards". 
Ideally it should also highlight only actual match without words in ignore phrase.
I'm thinking about kicking 2 queries and then removing results of ignore phrase from actual search. Is it somehow possible to get a list of matched tokens with their positions? Or is there any better approach? I can't add stop phrases to index, because search is dynamic, and ignore phrases vary from user to user.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure i quite fully understand your approach
however it sounds like you want to add to your query a must not query combined with an exact phrase match.
it would look a little something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "text_field" : "best" }
      },
      "must_not" : {
        query_string: {default_field: "text_field", query: '\"best regards\"'}
      },
   }
}
```

if you have multiple phrases to exclude the string syntax is:

```
'\"text"\ OR \"text1"\ OR ... \"textn\"'
```

also it took me some time to realise how powerful elasticsearch [custom analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) are, i'm not sure exactly how your data looks and what your needs are but if you haven't you should take a look into it, it might save you a lot of trouble and make your queries more efficient.